# Mutually independent Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

Let $A$ and $B$ and $C$ are mutually independent. Prove $B$ is independent from $(A\cap C)'$

The way is started is

\begin{eqnarray}
P(B∩(A∩C)' &=& P(B)P(A\cap C)'\\
 &=& P(B \cap (A∩C)' \\
 &=& P(B) + P(A \cap C)'-P(B \cup (A \cap C)')
\end{eqnarray}

But I keep getting stuck.

Comment: I added the things i've tried but i'm not sure if that's the way to start it and i keep getting stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(B \cap (A \cap C)')&= P(B)-P(B \cap A \cap C) \\
&=P(B)-P(B)P(A \cap C)\\
&=P(B)(1-P(A \cap C) ) \\
&=P(B)(P(A \cap C)')
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks so much, but i'm still confused as what the next step would be. I feel like it's simple but i'm overthinking it.

Comment: Just edited, any step that you don't get it?

Comment: I fully understand what you did, but i'm not sure how to proceed, to prove the answer.

Comment: isn't the question show that $B$ and $(A \cap C)'$ are independent?

Comment: Oh, i think i got it, does this prove its independent because, we showed that $P(B)(P(A∩C)')$

Comment: I think so. unless you have a different definition of "independence" from mine.

Comment: Yea, i believe what you did is right, Thanks so much.